# Bootstrap - two seperate columns but a row to span both

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

This is going to be hard to explain without an image but I'll do my best

```
--------------  --------------
| COLUMN 1    | | COLUMN 2    |
|             | |             |
| Col 1 Row 1 | | Col 2 Row 1 |
| Col 1 Row 2 | | Col 2 Row 2 |
| THIS NEEDS TO AGO ACROSS    |
| BOTH COLUMNS                |
| Col 1       | | Col 2       |
--------------- ---------------
```

So the bit in the middle is spacing between column 1 and column 2

This is the current setup without that bridge across the columns

```
<div class="row level-five hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md">
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="col-md-12 darkgreenbg">
            <p>COLUMN 1</p>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-10 lightgreenbg col-md-offset-1">
                    <p>COL 1</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-10 lightgreenbg col-md-offset-1">
                    <p>COL 1/p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-10 greenbg col-md-offset-1">
                    <p>COL 1</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-10 greenbg col-md-offset-1">
                    <p>COL 1</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="col-md-12 darkgreenbg">
            <p>COLUMN 2</p>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-10 lightgreenbg col-md-offset-1">
                    <p> COL 2</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-10 lightgreenbg col-md-offset-1">
                    <p>COL 2</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-10 greenbg col-md-offset-1">
                    <p>COL 2</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-10 greenbg col-md-offset-1">
                    <p>COL 2</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So something like the below. It already exists but obviously the badly edited picture shows what I'd like to happen for the bottom two boxes which currently look like the two top boxes.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Not sure what kind of content will be in there so this may not be possible, but it can be mocked up like this:

```
<div class="row level-five">
  <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="col-md-12">asdasdasd</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="col-md-12">asdasdasd</div>
    </div>
   <div class="col-md-12">asdasdasd</div>
   <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="col-md-12">asdasdasd</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="col-md-12">asdasdasd</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have amended the question with an image and better code